# CSS - Change the color names

Tags: css

In CSS have a way to change the color of color names?

Example:

```
background: white;
```

I want to change the color of the "white"... there's a way for this?

Comment: Why do you need this? You can use RGB or Hexadecimal.

Comment: If you want to change the colour, then you can do `background: #ccc` for example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using a CSS preprocessor such as: SASS to add functionality to CSS see http://sass-lang.com/guide

```
$font-stack:    Helvetica, sans-serif;
$primary-color: #333;

body {
  font: 100% $font-stack;
  color: $primary-color;
}
```

Comment: Hum, basically is this what i want. The SASS create variables for CSS, right?

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to achieve this in CSS, or at least none that I know of.

However, you may want to take a look at CSS preprocessors, such as [LESS](http://lesscss.org/) or [SASS](http://sass-lang.com/). Regardless of which one you choose, you gain the ability of declaring your own variables, e.g.

```
@white: rgb(250, 250, 250);
body {
    background-color: @white;
}
```